After upgrading to Expo SDK 52, my project have some error
Since upgrading to SDK 52, i got the message
(NOBRIDGE) ERROR  Error: Exception in HostFunction: Unable to convert string to floating point value: "large"
this is only occuring now so please tell me if it is because of any Library.
i updated all my library and checked all my styles with "large" in it but don't know what's wrong
Edit
It was the library. The date picker library is buggy rn so had to delete all the libraries and reinstall. Hope this help

Same here, please do not downvote the question. There is an issue out there, a lot of threads opened on different platforms.

So I found a way to make it work. I think it was regarding some faulty packages I had on my project, which I was not even using. So you can maybe try do the same as me:

Check packages using npx npm-checkand delete those from your pacakge.json
Update all packages by running npx npm-check -u including expo to v52
The to clean up everything I run rm -rf node_modules/ yarn.lock package-lock.json && cd ios && pod deintegrate && yarn &&  yarn start

After that, the project loaded on my physical device (should do the same on simulator) but some styling of the navbar is broken.

This worked for me, thank you

I have faced the same issue after the upgrade, what is works for me during the expo start - console prompt shows dependency warning and expected version to update, I have followed the version mentioned in console and recursively able to fix the build without any warning and look for the compatible version. In the end the build is fix and app is working with the updated version expo52 version. Do let me know if you need more help. Thanks !

I am running on this error:   Warning: Error: Exception in HostFunction: Unable to convert string to floating point value: "large"

I am also facing a lot of errors like top spacing changed, RTL stopped working in expo 52, and a lot of minor issues like disable not working, and expo-camera stopped working. Is there any update or fix for the newer version?
