Error: Exception in HostFunction: Unable to convert string to floating point value: "large"
My project was running successfully on expo 51 but after upgrading my expo sdk from 51 to 52 my project is giving me {Exception in HostFunction: Unable to convert string to floating point value: "large"} error on mobiles(Ios and android). However it is running on local web. I searched the text large in my project and i am not using large at any place.
Anyone knows how to solve this issue ?

same here... I'm just looking at this myself. I think its related to react-navigation/native and react-native-screens dependency being out of date with expo 52 and expo router being upgraded... not sure right now

Follow the solution here
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79191802/after-upgrading-to-expo-sdk-52-my-project-have-some-error

@mikejames I upgrade the dependencies by expo doctor and it works for me

I fixed the issue produced in expo-doctor npx expo --fix

After Upgrading every package will resolve this issue. In my case when I upgrade packages the error not produce again.

I had exactly the same problem and managed to solve it by adding the property below to the app.json file:
"newArchEnabled": true,

and I ran the commands below:
npx expo-doctor

then
npx expo install --check

The last command will basically analyze the possible errors in your project and at the end it will ask if you want to solve them automatically, just press the Y key and all the errors will be solved.
This worked for me, I hope it helps others.

Issued resolved, tested and worked for me.

I had the same issue and followed these commands, but it introduced a new error: Error: Cannot find module 'metro-cache' which had to be fixed with an npm install of metro-cache. Just in case anyone comes across the same error :)

using these commands in terminal worked for me:
$ npx expo-doctor@latest
$ npx expo install --check


just run

npx npm-check-updates -u

to update all the packages first
and delete the unnecessary pacakges

For some reason one library didn't update for me
I removed it and reinstalled it and everything was fixed
library: react-navigation/bottom-tabs

I also replaced "large" with 100 in  the only large I had in my .src in a HomeScreen
all "large" can be found by:
grep -rni ./src -e "large"
